# Bootstrap classes(card) don't work in asp.net view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display a grid of cards with information retrieved by the backend, but it seems that the bootstrap classes are not working as intended. The layout.cshtml view appears to display bootstrap properly, and other views I have do too. Don't know if its just something with the .card and row/col classes or is a larger issue.

```
     <div class="row">
@foreach (var product in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" style="width: 18rem;" src="@product.Url" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">@product.Title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">@product.Price</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

What the page looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngaBX.jpg

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Try clean and build. Also try debugging . It seems it does not serve the page with your change.

Comment: Create a [mcve]. With bootstrap, we need to see (be able to reconstruct) the entire page.

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/file/xpxtp8 Here is the project, you can view the grid as a normal user when logged in, you have to add an account to admin table to be able to create new items. Made it as simple as I could and the bootstrap on products/index path still isn't displaying properly.

Comment: Also, double-check what version of Bootstrap you are using. ASP.NET MVC utilizes Bootstrap 3, while I believe ASP.NET Core MVC uses Bootstrap 4; cards are available in Bootstrap 4 only, replacing panels, wells, and thumbnails from BS3.

Comment: Thats seems to be the problem, I replaced the default bootstrap file with one from bootswatch and had to change the navbar, but the rest of the functionality works now.